# Support for epics-base in yocto

Tags: yocto, nvidia-jetson, yocto-recipe, jetson-xavier

I am working on the Kirkstone branch to provide support for [epics](https://epics.anl.gov/license/index.php)  (Experimental Physics and
Industrial Control System)

I can see some information related to the EPICS license in spdx-licenses.json and "./files/common-licenses/EPICS". I am not sure if EPICS support is already available. Is it possible to bitbake EPICS by default? I wasn't able to do that? Any help is appreciated.

"bitbake epics" failed. I added custom recipe for epics but want to confirm if support is available by default.

Comment: What you found is only the license, which can be used by other projects also, and mostly used for SW-BoM generation. After some lookaround to me it looks like there is no official layer/recipe for epics-base, neither 1st nor 3rd party - you will have to create it yourself, or borrow it from someone else...